# Node.js Promise concurrency

Tags: node.js, promise, concurrency, request-promise

I am getting a weird unexpected output that I can't explain.

knowing that I am using Node.js and MongoDb, take a look at this code below (i):
[image]

is supposed to be faster then this code below (ii):
[image]

but weird enough I get this output in the console:
[image]

even though I am running block (i) before running block (ii), and if I switch those 2 blocks so that block (ii) gets executed before (i), this is what I get:
[image]
and sometimes I get 'seedRoles in NAN' in this case.

Can anyone explain this behavior in Node.js ?

Comment: Please do NOT post code in images - ever.  It can't be search indexed.  People trying to help you can't copy/paste code into answers.  It's harder to read on mobile and your first code block is even harder to read on my desktop.  In effect, you're asking anyone who wants to help you to retype, from scratch, code they want to include in an answer.  Please edit your question to change the code to text.

Comment: Benchmarking that involves a database is difficult.  The first operation you do may incur cost of loading tables, indexes, populating stuff into a cache, etc...  You have to somehow get the database and all of its internal state and the OS disk cache all in the exact same state before running each test.

Comment: Note, this question is really about database concurrency and how to do proper database benchmarking, not about promises at all.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help so far, so it has nothing to do with promises at all, nor about Node.js behavior. It is about mongoose isn't it ?